# An exception occurred while creating a query in EntityManager

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, jpql, entitymanager

This is my query.

```
List exp = entityManager.getEntityManager()
        .createQuery("select sum(u.expenseAmount), u.wdExpenseGroup.expenseGroupName from WdExpense u WHERE MONTH(CAST(u.expenseDate as date)) = MONTH(NOW()) AND YEAR(CAST(u.expenseDate as date)) = YEAR(NOW()) group by u.wdExpenseGroup.expenseGroupId")
        .getResultList();
```

I'm getting below error.

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: An exception occurred while
>   creating a query in EntityManager:  Exception Description: Syntax
>   error parsing the query [select sum(u.expenseAmount),
>   u.wdExpenseGroup.expenseGroupName from WdExpense u WHERE
>   MONTH(CAST(u.expenseDate as date)) = MONTH(NOW()) AND
>   YEAR(CAST(u.expenseDate as date)) = YEAR(NOW()) group by
>   u.wdExpenseGroup.expenseGroupId], line 1, column 91: unexpected token
>   [(]. Internal Exception: NoViableAltException(83!=[661:1:
>   simpleConditionalExpressionRemainder[Object left] returns [Object
>   node] : (n= comparisonExpression[left] | (n1= NOT )? n=
>   conditionWithNotExpression[(n1!=null), left] | IS (n2= NOT )? n=
>   isExpression[(n2!=null), left] );])

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

MONTH, YEAR, etc are not valid JPQL. 
See http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_4_0/jpa/jpql.html#JPQL_BNF_Notation